# How we can install npm and yarn in power pages

Tags: npm, command-line-interface

I want to use npm and yarn in power pages i have tried multiple things but not works . Just wanted to know it is possible to install npm and yarn in power pages. If yes does anyone has an idea.

I have tried using pcf and cli but not works

Answer (score 0):

I think it is not possible to install npm or yarn directly in power pages. Are you using Azure Devops for developing the power apps ?
If you are using this service then you can build pipeline, which supports installation of npm or yarn packages.